# Google App Engine with Wordpress and Custom Domain

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have a domain www.MYDOMAIN.com , and a GAE project at MYPROJECT.appspot.com , which has wordpress , along with the GAE plugins installed.

Most of the testing/updating has been done, and I would to show the app from www.MYDOMAIN.com. But there seems to be problems(css not loaded properly etc). On researching, I found that these errors occur when the website url is wrong. How do I correctly change the appspot domain to my custom domain?

Comment: What is the specific error and does any of the application load when calling from the domain?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few plugins that will update things for you when changing the hostname.

For example [Go Live Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/).

Answer (score 0):

The website seemed to be in a redirect loop.

```
if( is_production() ) {
            //add_filter( 'secure_auth_redirect', '__return_true' );
            //force_ssl_admin( false );

            defined( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT' ) or define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
            defined( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS' ) or define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );
        }
```

Commenting the top two lines in that function fixed the problem.

Also, this is my wp-config:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   define( 'WP_HOME','http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```